# Is bit (32 or 64 bit) of a processor an hardware or software context?

Tags: architecture, cpu, cpu-architecture

I have run into some cases where I really wish I have the right perspective to this bit-ness phenomenon. In developing a C# software in Visual Studio and had to use 3rd party libraries, the instruction sometimes include note to use library versions that are for 64 bit processors (e.g. [sqlite dlls](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)). Things like this and others made me believe that bit size of processor (i.e. 64 or 32 bit) is a software thing. Then again comes installation of OS and sometimes you hear something like "this ISO image is for 64 bit processors). When I realize that in computer stores, computers are advertised in terms of RAM and HD size, processor name and speed, etc. (e.g. 500GB HD, 4GB RAM, Intel Celeron Processor 2.2Ghz...) never heard 64 or 32 bit mentioned in that context.

From the above explanation,

1. Is 64 or 32 bit-ness a software (that is Installed Operating System)
   or hardware thing?
2. If above is true, is it safe to install a 64 bit
   OS (e.g. Ubuntu 64 bit OS) on just about any computer or there is
   hardware/processor consideration?

Comment: To make it simple: The CPU has "32-bit" and "64-bit" modes (if supported). The same machine code, say X, means different things for the two modes. This mode can be selected on a per-process basis (It's actually more involved than that), so each "thing" (like a DLL) loaded into the process address space must be of the same bitness. C# (or better ICL) doesn't have bitness, the CPU setting in VS means: create the interpreter as 32/64/default bit. Where default is the OS bitness.

Comment: Before 32-bit OSes were fully obsolete, you'd sometimes see an ad for a computer that came with 64-bit Windows vs. 32-bit.  Computer ads like you're talking about are always for systems including an OS, so what the CPU supports is only relevant for the OEM; they can choose to sell a 64-bit capable machine with a 32-bit OS (and actually still do on netbooks, because 64-bit Windows takes more space because it includes libraries for both, while 32-bit Windows has no use for 64-bit libraries).  With Linux, you could do a pure 64-bit install,  few PCs are sold with Linux.

Comment: This probably belongs on superuser where there's probably an existing duplicate, especially if you only care about x86 (you didn't tag it x86, though, so I tried to make my answer not totally x86 specific.)

Comment: This does not *exactly* have a duplicate on superuser. The related questions on superuser is not specifically to clarify the software/hardware context. However, your answer is very explicit and relevant.

Comment: @MargaretBloom so I guess your "if supported" explains the hardware relevance to the bit-ness. So how can I be sure that my CPU *'has "32-bit" and "64-bit" modes'*?

Comment: 32-bit is obsolete, all current x86 CPUs support 64-bit mode (except Geode microcontrollers...)  But in general, either look it up based on the model number (e.g. google `i7-6700k`), or check the CPUID feature bit: http://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64#How_do_I_detect_if_the_CPU_is_64_bits_.3F.  The most recent CPUs to not support Long Mode are Intel Atom, a couple generations before Silvermont.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ISO image should have said "this ISO image is for 64 bit OSes".  (Or hopefully more specifically x86-64 OSes, because x86 isn't the only ISA in the world.)

- A 64-bit kernel (long mode) can run 64-bit user-space (long mode) or 32-bit (compat mode).  This can only run on hardware that supports long mode (i.e. 64-bit capable).
- A 32-bit kernel (legacy mode) can only run 32-bit user-space (legacy mode).  It can also use vm86 mode to run 16-bit software, but a 64-bit kernel can't (without full virtualization like VirtualBox).

So a 32-bit OS can limit your 64-bit CPU to only ever running in 32-bit mode.

---

AFAIK those bullet points are generally true even outside of x86 (except for the names of the modes), although I'm not sure 64-bit MIPS and PowerPC are even different modes.  (i.e. there might have been room in the instruction-set to add 64-bit instructions without changing the meaning of existing instruction encodings the way x86-64 does).

64-bit ARM is a bit like x86-64: AArch64 is a new ISA, but some CPUs that support it can run ARM32 user-space processes (and maybe run ARM32 OSes, too).  But some newer Apple chips drop hardware support for 32-bit ARM mode entirely.  (AArch64 is a radical enough change that this is worth doing.  Unlike AMD64, where AMD was very conservative and barely cleaned up any of x86's warts in terms of things that make it hard to decode and run efficiently.  (e.g. shifts leave flags unmodified with count=0).  This saves transistors in the decoders and elsewhere because more can be shared with 32-bit mode.)

---

Before 32-bit OSes were fully obsolete, you'd sometimes see an ad for a computer that came with 64-bit Windows vs. 32-bit.

Computer ads like you're talking about are always for systems including an OS, so what the CPU supports is only relevant for the OEM; they can choose to sell a 64-bit capable machine with a 32-bit OS (and actually still do on netbooks, because 64-bit Windows takes more space because it includes libraries for both, while 32-bit Windows has no use for 64-bit libraries).

With Linux, you could do a pure 64-bit install, but few PCs are sold with Linux.  And it wouldn't save much space, because a normal Linux install only has a few key 32-bit libraries, not a 2nd copy of everything.  Still, a 64-bit install does tend to take more space than a purely 32-bit install.  Code-size is usually somewhat larger for x86-64, even when instruction counts are lower.

x86-64 also takes more RAM for programs with pointer-heavy data structures (unless you use an ABI like [x32: 32-bit pointers in long mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI)), which is another reason you still see some low-end computers with 32-bit Windows being sold.  A 32-bit OS may actually run better than a 64-bit one with 2GB or less of RAM.